# How to calculate quasi-norm of a vector?

Tags: r, vector, statistics

The idea of quasi-norm is the same of Lp norm but with `0<p<1`

If we use `type="2"` it means L2-norm and `type="1"` refer to L1-norm.

I have tried this in R, but does not work for quasi-norm.

So, I am wondering if someone could help with this, please?

```
e <- as.matrix(c(1,1,1,1,1)) 
norm(e, type="0.5")
```

Comment: `norm` does not have a `type = "0.5"`. What is a "quasi norm"? You need to give more information.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50271792/edit) your question to include additional information instead of posting as comments; people here are not necessarily familiar with the same concepts as you are, so you need to provide more details. *Be specific!* How do you *calculate* the quasi-norm for a vector, for a matrix? How did you get `type = "0.5"` for `norm`? This is not a valid `type`, so is this from some additional R library?

Comment: @Maurits Evers, it should be okay now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it is always helpful to check the documentation of a particular R-function:

```
?norm
```

gives you that `norm()`

> Computes a matrix norm of x using LAPACK. The norm can be the one ("O") norm, the infinity ("I") norm, the Frobenius ("F") norm, the maximum modulus ("M") among elements of a matrix, or the “spectral” or "2"-norm, as determined by the value of type.

and that the **only** valid arguments for *type* are

> "O", "o" or "1"
>   specifies the one norm, (maximum absolute column sum);
>
> "I" or "i"
>   specifies the infinity norm (maximum absolute row sum);
>
> "F" or "f"
>   specifies the Frobenius norm (the Euclidean norm of x treated as if it were a vector);
>
> "M" or "m"
>   specifies the maximum modulus of all the elements in x; and
>
> "2"
>   specifies the “spectral” or 2-norm, which is the largest singular value (svd) of x.

Second, to answer your question. You can implement a function to compute any Lp-norm of a vector yourself:

```
lpnorm <- function(x, p){
  n <- sum(abs(x)^p))^(1/p)
  return(n)
}
a <- matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8))
lpnorm(a, 1)
# 36
norm(a, type="1")
# 36
lpnorm(a, 2)
# 14.28286
norm(a, type="2")
# 14.28286
lpnorm(a, 0.5)
# 265.8857
```

Comment: It is usually bad practice to give the name of an existing function to your function. `pnorm` is already used to return quantiles of a normal distribution in base R.

Comment: Oh, true. My bad. I've changed the answer accordingly.